# How to make vuetify tooltip work in list?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

here's my code:

```
<div id='app'>
<v-app>
<v-list-tile-content>
<v-list-tile v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.id" >

  <v-list-tile-action>
    {{index+1}}.
  </v-list-tile-action>

  <v-tooltip bottom>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">

      <v-list-tile-content>
          <v-list-tile-title v-text="`${item.title}`"></v-list-tile-title>
      </v-list-tile-content>

    </template>
    <span>Tooltip</span>
  </v-tooltip>

</v-list-tile>
</v-list-tile-content>
</v-app>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/zbyszek-kisy/pen/RwWqarj

and I have no idea why tooltip is not showing when I'm trying to hover over the list item

Comment: You should do something about the error ~ _"[Vuetify] Unable to locate target [data-app]"_. You're also missing the `v-on="on"` binding on the activator element

Comment: codepen is fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to put the tooltip activator with the directive v-on="on" in each element where you want to activate it.

```
<div id='app'>
<v-app>
<v-list-tile-content>
<v-list-tile v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.id" >

  <v-list-tile-action>
    {{index+1}}.
  </v-list-tile-action>

  <v-tooltip bottom>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">

      <v-list-tile-content v-on="on">
          <v-list-tile-title v-text="`${item.title}`"></v-list-tile-title>
      </v-list-tile-content>

    </template>
    <span>Tooltip</span>
  </v-tooltip>

</v-list-tile>
</v-list-tile-content>
</v-app>
</div>
```

The funtional code: https://codepen.io/BernardoBernal/pen/dyYQXPj